# Javascript client C++ server game

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, socket.io

I have a question which path should I follow.

I want to develop real time online game via webbrowsers.

I would want to write game server using C++ with TCP sockets listening. The client side game will be written in javascript. The only problem I dont know how to communicate javascript with c++ server using TCP sockets. I have considered using Socket.IO but as far as I know this library does not have option to just connect to real TCP server, push bytes through and read incoming ones. Instead I would need to use some wrapper like Node.JS server which I want to avoid.

Anyone could guide me which path I should take?

Comment: If you want to be performant, and to be able to optimize, you're going to have to use socket.io with C++ bindings to node.js; don't worry too much though, creating c++ bindings in node are fairly straight forward, and you won't need to worry about performance(V8 has your back).

Comment: You can't do TCP from a web browser.  You can only do websockets.  And you would have to implement websockets in your c++ server, which is quite difficult.  Technically, you could implement a chrome application, but you can't just point a web browser at a url to play the game.

Comment: I would suggest only to support browsers that support WebSocket (The fallback methods will most likely not meet the requirements of realtime games) and use an existing standalone WebSocketServer c++ implementation as base (and there i would use an event based and not a thread base implementation).

Comment: Thank you very much for all suggestions!

I think I will try NODE.JS spawning C++ game server as library and push all data to it while reading incoming data.

I like Socket.IO idea a bit more because it has ability to use flash sockets as well as websockets and AFAIK they both are able to handle a game pace of 30 data exchanges per second. Thank you :)

Comment: Hello @Irav what was the final steps to solve this problem. I am also stuck in similar situations

Answer (score 1):

You could make your game server itself an HTTP server. For the most part it could just serve up your static files, but when it received a WebSocket upgrade request, it could handle that however it desired.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to websockify:

> [websockyfy](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) is a WebSocket to TCP proxy/bridge. This allows a browser
>   to connect to any application/server/service. Implementations in
>   Python, C, Node.js and Ruby.

Comment: For realtime games I would avoid such constructs, because it adds an additional layer of tcp buffering and piping data through the kernel.